# What effect does splitting the SSID have on gadgets around the home?

Tags: wireless-networking

We just switched to a BT Smart Hub 6 but couldn’t get our HEOS speakers to connect to our new network.Somebody at BT advised to try splitting the signal to 5ghz & 2.4ghz so we did this and it worked.Will this cause slower speeds on the other tech around the home now if they are only linked to the 5ghz signal and not the combined signal? If we were to re-merge the signals would this knock the speakers out again? We are not tech savvy people so ‘simple’ answers would be great!

Answer (score 1):

> Somebody at BT advised to try splitting the signal to 5ghz & 2.4ghz so we did this and it worked.Will this cause slower speeds on the other tech around the home now if they are only linked to the 5ghz signal and not the combined signal?

There is no such thing as "combined signal". You *always* have separate 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz signals, and devices connect only to one or the other. Usually the only difference is whether they have different names (SSIDs) or not. However, it has no direct effect on network speed.

What a single SSID (Wi-Fi network name) does is inform client devices that it's safe to *automatically roam* from one signal to another (be it different frequency on same AP, or different access point on same freq) while retaining the same IP address and without losing active TCP connections.

For example, a house might have a bunch of Wi-Fi access points in different locations broadcasting the same SSID, and your smartphone would move from weaker to stronger as you walk around. (This is how the recent "mesh Wi-Fi" products work.)

Meanwhile, if the SSIDs are different, your devices have no choice but to assume that they *might* connect to different networks, and will try to remain on the same SSID even if its signal becomes weak.

Though of course, this is only relevant to mobile devices. A stationary device such as a TV or speaker has no need to roam to begin with – it just picks the best signal once and stays on it.

(Unfortunately, some embedded Wi-Fi chips don't understand this concept of "same SSID, multiple signals" at all. Sometimes they pick the first signal they see even if stronger ones are available, and sometimes (like the one in my printer) they get so confused that they become unable to connect to a network *at all*.)

So if you end up having to use different SSIDs (network names) for 5 GHz and 2.4 GHz, it will have no effect on network speed by itself. The only potential difference will come from devices being reluctant to automatically hop from a weaker signal to a stronger one.

Comment: This, unfortunately my chromecast also can't be band-steered, even if it's meant to support it :(